# How to display JSON data in TableView (Swift)

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, realm, alamofire

Im a new in Swift and cant find right decision, how to modify my code to display JSON data in my TableView? I'm using Alamofire, SwiftyJSON, Realm.

JSON:

```
object      {4}

status  :   ok

source  :   techcrunch

sortBy  :   latest

articles        [10]

    0       {6}

    author  :   Darrell Etherington

    title   :   Tesla to triple service capability with repair fleet and service center expansion

    description :   Tesla is adding over 100 new service centers around the world, and putting over 350 new mobile service vans to work with its roaming fleet for house and work..

    url :   https://techcrunch.com/2017/07/11/tesla-to-triple-service-capability-with-repair-fleet-and-service-center-expansion/

    urlToImage  :   https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2017/07/serviceentrance.jpg?w=764&h=400&crop=1

    publishedAt :   2017-07-11T13:21:09Z

    1       {6}

    2       {6}

    3       {6}

    4       {6}

    5       {6}

    6       {6}

    7       {6}

    8       {6}

    9       {6}
```

My code is below:

1. Realm:

   ```
   class ArtFiles: Object {
       dynamic var title: String = ""
   }
   ```
2. Alamofire + JSON:

   ```
   class ArticlesData {

   func loadNews (title: String) {

           let firstURL = "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&sortBy=latest&apiKey=6b7c247d75914da0b7a53c8bb951c279"

           let realm = try! Realm()

           Alamofire.request(firstURL, method: .get).validate().responseJSON { response in

           switch response.result {
           case .success(let myValue) :
           let myJSON = JSON(myValue)
           let latestArticles = ArtFiles()
           latestArticles.title = myJSON["articles"]["title"].stringValue

           try! realm.write {
               realm.add(latestArticles)

           } case .failure(let error):
               print(error)

       }


   }
   }
   }
   ```
3. Working at ViewController with result:

   ```
   class ArticlesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
   @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

   var artArray : [String] = []
   let articlesData: ArticlesData = ArticlesData()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   print(Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL)

   for uploadArticles in artArray {
       articlesData.loadNews(title: uploadArticles)
   }

   self.tableView.reloadData()
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return artArray.count
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as? CustomTableViewCell

   cell?.titleLabel?.text = artArray[indexPath.row]

   return cell!
   }

   }
   ```

I see an empty rows. Cant understand, how to add JSON-data to the array, using my decision. Will be glad to your answers!

Comment: Where are you populating the array called `artArray`?

Comment: I created artArray to populate it with JSON data and display it in the tableView, but cant find right decision for it @Magnas .